# Error on clear data in group Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, razor, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I have a grid on Kendo UI that has GROUP, however an error occurs when I ask you to clean the grid data via JavaScript, follow the grid code Razor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ItemViewModel>(Model.FormasPagamento)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(clm =>
    {
        clm.Group(g => g.Title("FormaPagamento")
            .Columns(subitem =>
            {
                subitem.Bound(e => e.Dias)
                    .Title("Dias").Width(60).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:n0}', Dias)#");

                subitem.Bound(e => e.Percentual)
                    .Title("Percentual").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:p}', Percentual / 100)#");

                subitem.Bound(e => e.Valor)
                    .Title("Valor").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:n2}', Valor)#");
            })
        );
        clm.Group(g => g.Title("Parcela")
            .Columns(subitem =>
            {
                subitem.Bound(e => e.ParcelaValor)
                      .Title("Valor").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:n2}', ParcelaValor)#");

                subitem.Bound(e => e.ParcelaTaxa)
                      .Title("Taxa").Width(100).ClientTemplate("#=kendo.format('{0:n2}', ParcelaTaxa)#");

                subitem.Bound(e => e.ParcelaContratoCambio)
                      .Title("ContratoCambio").Width(200);

                subitem.Bound(e => e.ParcelaStatus)
                      .Title("Status").Width(80);
            })
        );
    })
      .ToolBar(t =>
      {
          t.Template("<span class=\"adicionarItemGridFormaPagamento k-button k-button-icontext\"><span></span>Adicionar</span>");
      })
      .Navigatable()
      .Editable(a =>
      {
          a.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell);
          a.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Excluir?");
      })
      .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
      .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
      .Filterable()
      .ColumnMenu()
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .DataSource(da => da
          .Ajax()
          .Batch(true)
          .PageSize(1000)
          .Events(e => e.Error("onErrorGrid"))
          .Destroy("", "", Model)
          .Create("", "", Model)
          .Update("", "", Model)
          .Model(m =>
          {
              m.Id(p => p.ItemId);
              m.Field(p => p.ParcelaValor).Editable(false);
              m.Field(p => p.ParcelaStatus).Editable(false);
              m.Field(p => p.ParcelaTaxa).Editable(false);
              m.Field(p => p.ParcelaContratoCambio).Editable(false);
          }))
)
```

Follows the JavaScript command to clear the grid data, when it reaches this point the browser code enters into an infinite loop and lock the application:

```
<script>
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.data([]); //ERROR
</script>
```

This problem does not occur with Kendo grid without GROUP, one would have any idea how to use this call without experience this bug?

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 and Kendo 2015.3.1111.545